# Which Konica AR to NEX E-mount adapters support manual (mechanical) aperture control?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, aperture, lens-mount, lens-adapter

I have a Tokina 28mm f/2.8 lens which uses a Konica AR mount. I am trying to adapt it to fit on an E-mount body. However, the lens has a manual mechanical aperture control (circled in yellow). Are there any non-electronic Konica AR to NEX E-mount adapters which include an aperture control lever directly on the adapter?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any lens with Konica AR mount (*) has an aperture ring for controlling the aperture, so I'm sure that no such adapter exists, as it would be completely redundant (and imprecise too).

The "AE" or "EE" position can't be used (it's equivalent to the slowest aperture). Just unlock the aperture ring, and choose the aperture on the lens. The camera needs to be in "M" or "A" mode.

(*) as long as the lens has an aperture at all - e.g. mirror lenses usually don't.

Comment: Aperture ring does not control the aperture unless some mechanism interacts with the coupling lever because coupling lever has a spring that keeps it in the fully closed down position until something pushing against it opens the diaphragm up in a measured amount. I have an osawa for konica 75-300 that has the same problem. The spring controlled lever keeps aperture fully closed and no adapter I've found changes that. Anyone know of a solution?